# Движение контура по кривой

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

Задача состоит в том, чтобы часть выделенная красным цветом двигалась по по основной траектории http://joxi.ru/gmvOPW3fxwb4j2 . 
Реализовать это пробовал различными способами через `svg`, но не получилось. Возможно это можно реализовать через `canvas`.

Пример моего кода:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
<article class="rel" role="article">
  <style>
    path {
      stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      fill: #fff;
    }

    path {
      animation: dash 2s linear;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;

      stroke-dasharray: 100, 1066;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1066;
        stroke-dasharray: 100, 966;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <svg id="layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         x="0px" y="0px" width="370px" height="460px" viewBox="0 0 370 460" 
         style="enable-background:new 0 0 370 460;" xml:space="preserve">
                   <style type="text/css">
                    .st0{fill:none;}
                   </style>
                   <path class="st0" d="M4.9,6c120,0,240,0,360,0c0.3,153.9,0.3,296.4-0.1,450c-8.2,0-16.5-0.2-24.7-0.2"/>
              </svg>
  </div>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что именно по вашему у вас не получилось?

Comment: У меня этот элемент пропадает из поля видимости. И получается обрывистая анимация

Comment: У вас сама линия в svg обрывистая, и длина ее не 1066, а ~834

Comment: Как вы узнали путь? И как можно получить непрерывный путь? Единственный способ о котором я знаю, это нарисовать его карандашом в иллюстраторе не отрывая руки. Любые преобразования линий в точки приводят к такому результату

Comment: Рисовать линии такие я, к сожалению, не умею. Возможно вам поможет какой-нибудь онлайн редактор svg. А длина линии узнается в js методом `.getTotalLength()`

Comment: Cheg, спасибо. Может подскажете какой-нибудь альтернативный вариант решения задачи?

Comment: Думаю, в интернете много уроков, в которых объясняется как это делается в AI. Если уж совсем беда, то, как вариант, можно нарисовать цельные фигуры все в том же AI и добавить под текст "Offer", "We are" фон, который будет перекрывать часть линий

Comment: Вот такой пример вот для рисования линий.
https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/dGwZBx